# The scroll attribute doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a scrollable item list through this code:

HTML page

```
<body onload="startPage()">
  <div class="datas"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript page

```
for(i = 0; i < Data.getNomCount(); i++) {
  //alert(Data.getNom(i));

  $(".datas").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='./css/style2.css'/>");
  $(".datas").append("<div class='myp'>");
  $(".datas").append("<ul>");
  $(".datas").append("<li >" + Data.getAdresse(i) + "</br>" + Data.getPrenom(i) + "</li>");
  $(".datas").append("</ul>");
  $(".datas").append("</div>");
}
```

CSS file

```
.myp {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

this code is not working, but when I put the class into the li tagn it works (but not the scroll attribute)... I want to scroll the different elements.

Comment: what is the max-height set? you must set a height after which the element will scroll on overflow

Comment: you are right, but I want to scroll while I have elements on my list. I put **height: auto;** but it doesn't work

Comment: first set a `min-height` then set the `max-height`. `max-height` is for scroll.

Comment: Height auto will never make you scroll. Its like you need to set some height to the element, and if the element height exceeds this value then it will show the scroll bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works